# Can I apply the variable separation method in this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

after applying the variable separation method to a 2D problem, suppose, I have the following equation

$a\frac{f(x)}{\frac{d\{f(x)\}}{dx}}+b\frac{g(y)}{\frac{d\{g(y)\}}{dy}}=c$
where $a,b,c$ are constants and a 2D function $F(x,y)$ has been decomposed as $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.
Since the left hand side is equals to a constant, can I write

$a\frac{f(x)}{\frac{d\{f(x)\}}{dx}}=P$
and $b\frac{g(y)}{\frac{d\{g(y)\}}{dy}}=Q$

where $P$ and $Q$ are constant with $P\neq Q$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true.

You have two functions $r$ and $s$, such that $r(x)+s(y) = c$, where
$$r(x) = a\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)},$$
and
$$s(y) = b\frac{g(y)}{g'(y)}.$$

Let $y_1\neq y_2$, and fix some $x_0$. Then
$$r(x_0)+s(y_1) = c,$$
$$r(x_0)+s(y_2) = c.$$
Subtract the first equation from the second to obtain
$$s(y_2)-s(y_1) = 0.$$
This means that $s(y_2)=s(y_1)$. We chose arbitrary $y_1$ and $y_2$, so the value of $s(y)$ is the same for all $y$, meaning that $s$ is a constant function. Likewise for $r$.